# Youtube content script loads but render inside the DOM after doing a reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build and extension for youtube for which I need to manipulate its DOM. The Dom manipulation thing works but not the first load but after reloading the page for once.

The code for my changed script file:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./src/App";
import "./src/index.css";

declare const chrome: any;

if (typeof browser === "undefined") {
  var browser = chrome;
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'my-extension'}>
        <App />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

  function addReactApp() {

    if(!location.pathname.startsWith('/watch')){
      return;
    }

    const sideBox = document.getElementById("secondary"); 
    const sideBox_inner = document.getElementById("secondary-inner");
    const videoPlayer = document.getElementsByClassName("html5-video-container");

    console.log("videoPlayer",videoPlayer)
    console.log("sideBox_inner",sideBox_inner)
    console.log("sideBox",sideBox)

    if (sideBox && sideBox_inner && videoPlayer) {
      const app = document.createElement("div");
      app.id = "tubechat-ai";

      sideBox.prepend(app);

      const container = document.getElementById("tubechat-ai");
      console.log("container",container)

      if (container) {
        const root = createRoot(container);

        root.render(
          <React.StrictMode>
            <Main />
          </React.StrictMode>
        );
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Not all required elements are present.");
    }
  }

document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-finish', addReactApp);

if (document.body) addReactApp();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addReactApp);
```

Manifest File for extension :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tubechat.ai",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://www.youtube.com/*",
    "https://www.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "my-assets/logo.png",
      "48": "my-assets/logo.png",
      "128": "my-assets/logo.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "my-assets/logo.png",
    "48": "my-assets/logo.png",
    "128": "my-assets/logo.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "css": ["my-assets/index.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js" 
  }
}
```

I have tried to change the manifest by putting the `run_at` tag in the content script but that also didn't work

Comment: Did you check the script is getting injected properly for the first time?

Comment: Yes it has been injected properly. At the start I get : "No tags found in the added node " in my console